# Why do we combine several select statements

Tags: sql, oracle

This question might be silly , but why do we combine several select statements in SQL. I did not find an answer for this yet.
Example:

```
 select OrderID from (SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
 FROM Customers
 INNER JOIN Orders
 ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
 ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName);
```

Comment: Preparing to do something more complex, or stripped down something more complex? As it is now it doesn't make much sense...

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the "Relational" part of "Relational database"

A relation is a set of rows, and can therefore be:

1. The rows in a table
2. The rows projected from a view
3. The rows projected from a query
4. The rows projected from a common table expression

In theory, all of these are the same, and so selecting from a table is logically the same as selecting from a view, or from another query, and joining two tables is logically the same as joining two queries.

As to why it is done, here are three decent reasons:

1. To avoid having to save a temporary result set into some structure and then read it out again.
2. Because in some cases it is not possible to place a condition on a query through a WHERE or HAVING clause, and the predicate must be placed on the result set.
3. Coding convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Output of this query will be all the orders which are having customer in customer table and it will not give any order which does not having any entry in customer table.  Moreover orders will be come in ascending order of their customerName value.